# How to use Gradle resolutionStrategy to force dependency version?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I am using Android support library `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0`. However, I am also using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0`, which depends on an earlier version of the support library.

To fix this, I used a `resolutionStrategy` to force the support library to be version 28.0.0, but it isn't working. Android Studio is still complaining about conflicting dependencies. Why isn't my resolution strategy working?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "rstudio.vedantroy.swarm"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    }
}

dependencies {

    //Developer-added dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:mvrx:0.7.0'


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this configuration for all support library version to be unified:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "28.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

This code snippet will find each dependency who has group name `com.android.support` and forcefully apply the version `28.0.0`, even to the internal dependencies. This way, you can also specify other dependencies projectwide to use explicit version, e.g. picasso or glide. You just need to specify its group and specify its specific version in `details.useVersion`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am having below error  while upgrading the new google place library  `Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.location.places.zza found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:16.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.8.0)`  how  can i force to use one from duplicate class using above example by you

Comment: I'm having an error that -- No candidates found for method call resolutionStrategy.

Comment: The API might have changed with Gradle 8. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html for the current API

Answer (score 4):

If anyone need, the script for Gradle Kotlin DSL is the following way：

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency {
            when (requested.module.toString()) {
                "androidx.fragment:fragment" -> useVersion("1.3.0")
                // ...etc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also you may want to take a look at the [official docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html).

Answer (score 1):

With Gradle 8 the solution is different:

com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    // maybe, you also need this
    // forcedModules = ['com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0']
  }
}
```

More information at https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html.