# Why java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.Argon2Parameters$Builder when using Argon2PasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I have this exception when calling the following code:

```
val encoder=Argon2PasswordEncoder.defaultsForSpringSecurity_v5_8()
val ok=encoder.matches("password","$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$fhPPCUS3Yo9snJkF.....")
```

Here is my build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    //val kotlinVersion="1.7.22"
    val kotlinVersion="1.8.10"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.3"
    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("kapt") version kotlinVersion
}


group = "deegixl.framework"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.springframework.session:spring-session-jdbc")

    implementation("commons-validator:commons-validator:1.7")

    //implementation("jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api")
    //implementation("org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator")
    implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0:jakarta")

    val openHtmlToPdfVersion="1.0.10"
    implementation("com.openhtmltopdf:openhtmltopdf-core:$openHtmlToPdfVersion")
    implementation("com.openhtmltopdf:openhtmltopdf-pdfbox:$openHtmlToPdfVersion")

    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

    runtimeOnly("com.mysql:mysql-connector-j")
    //implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.32")

    kapt("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    kapt("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")

    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:6.1.4")

    implementation("org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.76")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict","-Xcontext-receivers")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The bouncycastle lib ("org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.76") is included in the build.gradle.kts. I checked into the corresponding jar and the class  org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.Argon2Parameters$Builder.class is present so I don't understand why I have this problem.

Comment: is it present in the right scope? is there a mismatch in versions?

Comment: @Stultuske how can I know?

Answer (score 1):

For unknown reasons Gradle didn't refresh, that was the reason.
I did a manual refresh and it is working...

Comment: Good catch. Upvoted. I have included additional suggestions in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77160986/6309).

Comment: You can offer yourself a bounty LOL.

Answer (score 0):

The [OP Javaddict](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5920099/javaddict) do [mention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77193145/6309):

> For unknown reasons Gradle didn't refresh, that was the reason. I did a manual refresh and it is working..

If a manual refresh of the Gradle project resolved the issue, it is likely that the build system had not properly updated its internal state or downloaded the necessary dependencies. Gradle caches dependencies and build artifacts, and under certain circumstances, this can lead to inconsistencies between the project's configuration and the actual state of the build.

In cases like this, performing a manual refresh forces Gradle to reevaluate the project, update its caches, and potentially re-download dependencies, making sure the build is consistent with the project's current configuration.

For future reference, here are some steps to manually ensure that Gradle is fully updated:

```bash
./gradlew clean
./gradlew --refresh-dependencies
./gradlew build
```

If you are using an IDE like IntelliJ IDEA, you can also refresh the Gradle project from within the IDE. Typically this is done by clicking the "Refresh" button in the Gradle tool window.
Sometimes IDEs can hold onto outdated information. Restarting the IDE can also help in resolving such issues.

---

Original answer:

> how can I know?

To determine whether a class is present in the right scope and to identify any potential version mismatch, you can:

#### Verify Dependency Scope

- Check the Build Configuration: Review the [`build.gradle.kts`](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-kotlin-dsl) file to ensure that the dependency is listed under the correct scope (`implementation`, `runtimeOnly`, etc.). If the dependency is declared in a scope like `compileOnly`, it would not be available at runtime.
  See also "[Declaring dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html)"
- Inspect the Artifact: Examine the generated JAR or WAR file of your application to ensure that the dependency is indeed packaged correctly. You can usually find these files in the `build/libs` directory of your project.
- Run the Application: make sure the JVM's classpath is configured to include the required dependencies. How to do this would depend on how you are running the application (IDE, command line, application server, etc.).

#### Identify Version Mismatch

- List Dependencies: Run the command `./gradlew dependencies` in your project directory. That will provide a tree of all dependencies, allowing you to spot any multiple versions or conflicts. Look specifically for different versions of the Bouncy Castle library.

  ```bash
  ./gradlew dependencies
  ```
- Forced Resolution: If a conflict is detected, you can use [Gradle's `resolutionStrategy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77044767/6309) to force a particular version.

  ```kotlin
  configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy {
          force("org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.76")
      }
  }
  ```
- *Dependency Insight: For a deeper analysis of a specific dependency, you can use [Gradle's `dependencyInsight` task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#dependency_insights):

  ```bash
  ./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency bcprov-jdk18on
  ```

4. **Check Runtime**: Sometimes dependencies may behave differently at runtime due to various class-loading mechanisms. Consider adding debug or log statements in your code to print the versions of the library classes being used. That can be done using the class's `Package` object.

   ```kotlin
   println(Argon2Parameters::class.java.`package`.implementationVersion)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `bcprov-jdk18on:1.76`, but `spring-security-crypto:6.1.4"` depends on `bcprov-jdk15on:1.70` - see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/6.1.x/dependencies/spring-security-dependencies.gradle#L52 - which results in incorrect lib at runtime.

If you don't strictly need the version you've specified, I would suggest using one provided by spring.

If you do need, you can try applying resolution strategy as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77160986/3636639